# PHP While Loop - Hidden Input Values - SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to shows a number of rows one after the other, with a verify button underneath, which one clicked will go to the update (php) method. I've got it working, however it is always the same value (first alphabetical last name).

What I need to try and do is get it to pick the lastname from the row when submitted. Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="update.php" method="POST">
        <?php
        //executes the SQL query
         $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Sheet1");
         //returns the result from the database
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $census = $row['Date'];
            $WebsiteAddress = $row['WebsiteAddress'];
            $LastName = $row['LastName'];

            echo "<input type='hidden' name='HiddenInput' value='".$LastName."'>";

            echo "<b>Last Name:</b> $LastName<br><br> <b>Website:</b> $WebsiteAddress<br><br> <b>Date:</b> $census<br><br>";

            echo "<input name='".$LastName."' type='submit' value='Verify' /><hr>";
         }
        ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create array of input to get all the values like

```
<input type='hidden' name='HiddenInput[]' value='".$LastName."'>
```

Then $_POST['HiddenInput'] will return array that contain all value of $LastName

Comment: Thanks for the input, if I do this, the echo returns "Array"

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this code..  give different names to all the hidden fields..

```
 $i = 0;    
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $census = $row['Date'];
                    $WebsiteAddress = $row['WebsiteAddress'];
                    $LastName = $row['LastName'];

                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='HiddenInput_".$i."' value='".$LastName."'>";

                    echo "<b>Last Name:</b> $LastName<br><br> <b>Website:</b> $WebsiteAddress<br><br> <b>Date:</b> $census<br><br>";

                    echo "<input name='".$LastName."' type='submit' value='Verify' /><hr>";
                    $i++;
                 }
```

Comment: I cant have the hidden input being different values as they need to be the same as the last name. This is because I match the hidden input value with the last name in the database to form a WHERE query

Comment: @Frog82 but when you loop through mysql query.. than your lastname will be different every time?